# How to exchange 1T data between multiple processes?

Tags: design, data, caching, serialization

How to exchange 1T data between multiple processes?

Requirements:

1. Data < 1TB. Memory > 1T.
2. Multiple processes (different languages) on the same machine or different machines over network
3. Data should be available for 1 hour for fast read
4. Guarantee completeness of data.

I am thinking using JSON or Redis or 0MQ as the solution. Are there other solutions? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: Try any approach. Hit the wall. Understand why you hit the wall, and either optimize or change approach. Rinse and repeat until satisfied.

Comment: What kind of data? What kind of application? What operating system?

Comment: What do you mean by "1T"? Do you mean "1TB"?

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense to me - there is way too much lacking information to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Read much more about [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) (e.g. [this](http://www.ocoudert.com/blog/2011/07/09/a-practical-guide-to-c-serialization/)) and [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) and [distributed data store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_data_store) and [big data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data) and [data science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science). There are libraries, formats like [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation), tools like [SWIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG) which could help. Consider keeping the data in some centralized [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) server ([PostGresQL](https://postgresql.org/), [MongoDb](https://www.mongodb.com/), [Cassandra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra) ...). Read about the [challenge of Distributed Database Systems](https://berb.github.io/diploma-thesis/original/061_challenge.html), [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) and [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) and [π calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus). Read about [middleware for distributed applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware_(distributed_applications)).

If you use any relational database, put efforts on defining well your [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) and [database indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) and be aware of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

If the processes involved are on the same computer, read about [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface), [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory). So read much more about [operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

On Linux, see also [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), [mq_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html)

Textual formats and [text based protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) like [JSON](https://json.org/), [HJSON](https://hjson.org/), [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), [s-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) could be helpful (easier to debug) but requires CPU time to be parsed. So read about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). Given that CPU are a lot faster than disks (see http://norvig.com/21-days.html ...) there are situations where compressing the data (using lossless compression à la [zlib](https://www.zlib.net/)) before storing it on disk is worthwhile.

The devil is in the details. Put efforts on documentation of your software architecture and data format. The data (and its collection) usually costs more than the software processing it.

### Your question is really too broad. I tried to give some hints.

PS. You could get a PhD in solving your problem efficiently. Look into ACM conferences (e.g. [this](https://www.acm.org/data-science-summit) one) and [ACM papers](https://dl.acm.org/) related to it.